# How to check spark plugs on a Yamaha R6

Tags: motorcycle, sparkplugs

I was hit a few weeks ago and have been trying to get my motorcycle fixed ever since.  2012 Yamaha R6.  I replaced the tank among other things and trying to start it it sounds like it's sucking air.  Checked all the lines and everything seems fine.  The pump is working and loading the rail with gas when I turn it on.  The heads are sucking for air so those are fine.  The last thing I'm checking is spark.  I pulled the radiator off and pulled all the plugs out but from here I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't look like you've actually removed the plugs, just the coil packs from each of the plugs.  The plugs will be down the hole once the coil packs are removed.  you'll need a deep socket to get them out.

Comment: @davidcondrey    Did you get this resolved?  Hope so, love your bike.  A real runner.

Comment: I must've been having a blonde day that day.. lol  I tear my bike down, pull the engine out, work on everything else and put it back together no problem.. just don't ask me to change a sparkplug.  *smack*

Comment: I would have kept the original images in as that shows what you were missing.  Others may have the same confusion now and not know what they are doing is an incomplete step.

Answer (score 1):

The things that you pulled out are the ignition coils. If you want to check for spark get a spark tester. Plug the coil under test back into it's connector but still hanging out of the engine. Insert the spar tester into the coil where the spark plug would. Don't forget to ground the spark tester to the engine block. Crank the engine looking for a spark. Be careful not to shock yourself.

If you want to look at the spark plugs then you need to use a spark plug socket and an extension to reach the spark plug inside the hole that the coil came out of.